# How to find server-specific wkhtmltopdf settings?

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

My project has several PDFs that are generated using wkhtmltopdf. The PDFs print as expected locally, however on the server everything is different! Things that fit on the page on my local setup now are wrapping, columns are all screwed up because the width of the page seems to be different somehow even though I set a specific pixel width to the pages and the content.

The only thing I can think of is that the settings for wkhtmltopdf on my server are different than those on my local machine.

I've been trying to figure out how to find what those settings are, but I'm not sure!

Is there a way to even print them directly to the page so that I can see what they are and match them between the two environments?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3189)

Comment: As far as I know you pass settings as command-line arguments, not in a settings file. It's most likely that you aren't using the same version or you don't have the same fonts available.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I've made sure the version is identical and the fonts are all explicitly stated and work correctly (as well as on other parts of the site)

Comment: Settings aside, wkhtmltopdf is basically a browser and it relies on system libraries, particularly the font server. If everything else is identical the difference might lay there. Perhaps you can find information about the specific issues you're facing regarding your specific operating system.